# What should I use in a Xamarin multiplatform app to make a scrolling list?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am writing a small app to retrieve data from the Discogs API so that the user can scroll through items in their collection. Which control should I use, and how do I handle paging so that it loads the next x results when it gets to the end of the list?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

[TableView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview) -- for heterogenius content
[ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/index) -- for homogenius content

Infinite scroll is handled via lazy loading which Listview supports inherently via the `ItemsSource` data source property.

Answer (score 1):

If you use xamarin.forms you can add listview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

or for native xamarin.ios and xamarin.android check [UICollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview) and [RecyclerAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/)